# QGIS graphical modeler add field: error executing algorithm?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-2, error, qgis-modeler

I have to add more than 20 fields to a lot of shapefiles using QGIS 2.4. I used to do it with the tablemanager plugin.  Beside it is time consuming, misstakes can be made. So I want to automate that procedure through the graphical modeler.

[image]

I tested it with adding 2 fields and everything worked fine.  But when I added all the algorithms it gave an error:

> Error executing algorithm 2 [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor See log for more details

The log says:

`Uncaught error while executing algorithm
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 217, in execute
    self.processAlgorithm(progress)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\AddTableField.py", line 75, in processAlgorithm
    self.getParameterValue(self.INPUT_LAYER))
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\dataobjects.py", line 215, in getObjectFromUri
    print _loadedLayers
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`

After a few hours I tried to run the model again without changing anything and then this error appeared: Error executing algorithm 6 [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor See log for more details

In the log the same explanation as above.

Can anyone help me understand what's happening here?

Comment: I did a test and it worked fine for me. For your final algorithm, enter a name for the _Output layer_. When you run the model, you will be prompted to output the final layer as a temporary layer or save it in a directory (whichever you want). See if this works.

Comment: Hi Joseph, In my initial model I already gave a name for the outputlayer in my final algorithm. I think it has something to do with the temporary files the model create during the process.  When I empty /appdata/local/temp/processing, the error appears later on in the process (around 10th algrorithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed version 2.6.1 and now the model works without problems.